# Regex to replace right square brackets inside outer square brackets

Tags: .net, regex, mdx

I'm attempting to escape an MDX member reference using RegEx unsuccessfully.

This is the input string:

```
[dim[e]nsion].[this] [member] name]
```

This is what I'm attempting to output:

```
[dim[e]]nsion].[this]] [member]] name]
```

(notice the double right square brackets)

How would I accomplish this with RegEx using .Net?

More examples:

```
Input:  [dim[en]sion n[a]me ].[this [member] name]

Output: [dim[en]]sion n[a]]me ].[this [member]] name] 

Input:  [[dimension] name].[this member [name]]

Output: [[dimension]] name].[this member [name]]]
```

Comment: Regex cannot handle matching like that. It has no way of referring to "inside." You can probably accomplish some crazy lookahead expression that might work, but I strongly recommend using something more advanced than regular expressions.

Comment: Why is the `]` after `this` escaped?

Comment: Could you provide a few more example inputs and outputs?  It's not quite clear to me how the left and right sides of that dot character might be formatted...

Comment: MDX spec indicates that every right square bracket needs to be doubled in order for it to be escaped.

Comment: In your first and second example, there is no extra square bracket at the end, however there is in your last example?  Can you explain this logic?

Comment: Regex is not the right tool.  You do know how to check mark the right answer?

Comment: I'm perfectly aware that I could loop through the entire string and replace what needs to be replaced. I would like to use something more efficient than this though. Would Linq provide any functionality related to this problem?

Comment: See my answer below for a regular expression, however I am interested to know whether you will have whitespace after the closing ] ever?

Comment: Why do you assume looping is not the most efficient approach to this problem?  LINQ is just syntax that enumerates a string.   You could get there with Regex look behinds but I seriously doubt it would be faster this is a simple liner analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No looping is necessary.  We want to match every right-hand bracket but the last one and the one that immediately precedes the dot (`.`) separator.  We simply require that our right-hand bracket is followed by a single character and specify that it must be a non-dot character.  I'm not sure about the proper .NET way to say this, but you want to match on `]([^\.])` and replace with `]]$1` where `$1` is a backreference to the stuff in parentheses in the match pattern.  If you expect whitespace at the end of your input(s), I'd suggest cleaning that first, as this would replace the last `]` if it were followed by a space.

You can test here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

**EDIT 1:** Verified using the above tester: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msh1E.jpg

**EDIT 2:** Verified with `sed` (needed to get to a real computer):

```
~ $ echo "                              
[dim[e]nsion].[this] [member] name]
[dim[en]sion n[a]me ].[this [member] name]
[[dimension] name].[this member [name]]
" > input.txt
~ $ cat input.txt

[dim[e]nsion].[this] [member] name]
[dim[en]sion n[a]me ].[this [member] name]
[[dimension] name].[this member [name]]

~ $ sed 's/]\([^\\.]\)/]]\1/g' input.txt

[dim[e]]nsion].[this]] [member]] name]
[dim[en]]sion n[a]]me ].[this [member]] name]
[[dimension]] name].[this member [name]]]

~ $
```

**EDIT 3:** In the initial answer, the match pattern is given as `]([^\.])` with the dot (`.`) escaped to indicate that it is a literal dot character.  Depending on your language, you may need to escape other characters in the match.

Comment: Andrew, I tested this out and it neither match seemed to take care of it. You can assume that there is no whitespace after the closing bracket

Comment: Sorry, but the regular expression is correct.  I have demonstrated it using the testing tool linked above ( regular-expressions.info ) and uploaded the results here: http://imgur.com/a/VfR7W  The issue you're experiencing is probably due to escaping or a syntax issue.  Could you please provide the actual code you are using to perform this find/replace?

Comment: Andrew... this definitely solved the problem! I really didn't think it would be possible. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Rules are pretty simple insert ] on ] but only if after [

```
string str = "[dim[e]nsion].[this] [member] name]";
char[] chars = str.ToArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
bool leftLast = false;
foreach (char c in chars)
{
    sb.Append(c);
    if (c == '[')
    {
        leftLast = true;
    }
    else if (leftLast && c == ']')
    {
        sb.Append(']');
        leftLast = false;
    }
}
Debug.WriteLine(str);
Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Regex would find every ']' then apply a look back.
This char[] loop eliminates needless back analysis.
If lastLeft is false then no reason to even compare.